# excel 2021 to save as picture in png 32 bits

Tags: excel, image, save-as

on excel 2007, it save PNG in 32 bits.
the same excel document macros on excel 2021 saves the png in 8 bits and that causes issues with my laser engraver.

how can I get excel 2021 to save in png 32 bits (or any other bit depth)?

thanks

thanks all for you help!